# why does a jquery selector return an array instead of the element itself?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

If i have some mark-up that looks like:

```
<div class="box">
</div>
```

why does doing a jquery selector`$('.box')` return the element in an array?

i get an output in the console as:

```
[<div class="box"></div>]
```

and not:

```
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Because that's how it was designed, though it's not an Array. It's a jQuery object.

Comment: If it could return either a collection or a single element, you'd have to type-check the result to find out what you can do with it. That would be a serious drag.

Comment: Well, technically it *does* return the element you want in the form of a jQuery object, even thought it might be in an array form this shouldn't really affect what you're doing. Does it?

Comment: Because consistency is a good thing.

Comment: $('.box').get(0). if you has 2 .box,return a array.So do you know what $(".box") is a array or a object?

Answer (score 3):

A (valid) selector is not guaranteed to match a single element, but it *is* guaranteed to *represent a set of matched elements* that may

- be empty,
- have one element, or
- have more than one element.

This set is best represented by a collection object containing zero or more elements.

If you had markup consisting of more than one `.box` element, what would you expect jQuery to return if not a collection consisting of both elements? `document.querySelector()` is different in that the *method* is designed to return the first matching element per spec, which is why `document.querySelectorAll()` exists (which is what jQuery uses internally before defaulting to its own implementation).

Answer (score 1):

From [Rick Strahl](http://www.devx.com/codemag/Article/40923) description

Selectors return a jQuery object known as the "wrapped set," which is an array-like structure that contains all the selected DOM elements. You can iterate over the wrapped set like an array or access individual elements via the indexer ($(sel)[0] for example). More importantly, you can also apply jQuery functions against all the selected elements.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's not an array, it's an array-like jQuery object. You can use the object that `$()` returns just like you would when you chain your methods together like `$().css().append()`.

The other reason it's array-like is because the selector you provide can actually grab many different elements, and most of the methods you can call on a jQuery object will affect all dom elements that your selector selected.

I hope this helps, and I do hope you do a bit more research into jQuery and how it works. It's an extremely useful library that it appears you don't yet fully comprehend.

Edit: As others have mentioned, if you do just want an element from a jQuery object and just use jQuery as a selector, you can use bracket accessors `$(...)[0]` or the get method `$(...).get(0)`.